# Vue.js v-for with v-model

Tags: vue.js

**error:'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'msg' itself  vue/valid-v-model**

```
<div v-for="(msg,name) in normal" :key="name">
<input type="text" v-model="msg">
</div>
    <script>
export default{
data(){
normal: {
        position: "bottom",
        message: "",
        open: false,
        timeout: 1500,
      }}}
</script>
```

Comment: `data` not `date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit array/object variable from data directly. While accessing "msg" inside "for" loop you are only getting copy of item value, and not reference to object/array item.

The correct usage will be:

```
<div v-for="(msg, name) in normal" :key="name">
   <input type="text" v-model="normal[name]">
</div>
```

Comment: Based on Your code there should be 4 inputs. Type something in normal.message. Input still empty? You need to provide some fiddle for this.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Oops,it's my bad,I type```v-model="normal['name']"```and make the error

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   <v-checkbox
        v-for="(value, key, index) in activeDays"
        v-model="activeDays[key]"
        :key="index"
        :label="`${key}`"
        ></v-checkbox>
    
    
    
activeDays: {monday:false, tuesday:false}
```